# Remote login to mac

Tags: windows, ssh, mac, remote-access

I have a Mac Mini that I would like to login remotely from a Windows XP laptop.  Is this possible?  What types of things do I need to do to allow remote connections from the Mac, and what type of interface will I be able to have?  (Command-line interface?  Or full GUI interface?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

SSH is installed by default on OS X.  You just need to download PuTTY on your Windows machine and connect to your IP.  SSH provides console access.

If you want a GUI you can use VNC.

Comment: Yes. Remote SSH access is disabled by default though... You will have to enable it: Settings/Sharing

Comment: Mac OS X also includes a VNC server by default. Just enable Screen sharing and activate VNC using a password in the config. No encryption though.

Answer (score 6):

You can remotely log on to a Mac from a PC using VNC.  Instructions for setting up a Mac as a VNC serve can be found [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Setup-VNC-on-Mac-OS-X) and [here](http://howto.diveintomark.org/remote-mac/).  For the PC, any VNC client should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable the ssh daemon on your mac by going to

System Preferences.app -> Sharing -> (enable) Remote Login

You can enable screen sharing similarly with

System Preferences.app -> Shareing -> (enable) Screen Sharing.

If you are not using the Apple Remote Desktop software, you'll need to do the extra step of clicking on the Computer Settings button, and supplying a VNC password

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the free option, but if you have two macs running Leopard and a MobileMe account you can use Back To My Mac to connect to the other mac's desktop. [Here](http://www.apple.com/mobileme/features/mac.html#btmm-quicktour) is a quick screencast of this feature.

Comment: You can also establish a screen-sharing connection, without MobileMe, using iChat.

Answer (score 0):

I use these this web site.  You need to sign up but you can access you choosen computer.  I use to to fix my dad's computer.  I use the basic free versio.  Works fine with both Mac and PC
https://secure.logmein.com/